# Golang Channels - Help me get my head around this

Tags: go, goroutine, channel

Trying to get 2 Goroutines to play nicely within my project. Even though this is all sorta working, I am 100% sure it is being done very poorly... maybe even wrong...ly (is that even a word?).

Anyway, the basic concept of this project is to run some repeated work over a pre-selected amount of time while allowing the ability to abort the run before the time is up.

Here's the mess I have so far (I've only included the important parts for everyone's sanity... and to hide my horrible coding):

Two Goroutines:

1. `BenchTimer()` is a simple run-time countdown timer that does some repeating work for a set amount of time.
2. `AbortTest()` is a keyboard listener used to catch an 'ESC' (or whatever else I want) keypress from the keyboard to act as a "User Abort".

Each Goroutine, upon a successful run (i.e. `BenchTimer()` completes the countdown **OR** `AbortTest()` catches an abort keypress), sends a message down a common channel `testAction`. I use the one channel since this is an **OR** kinda thing (i.e. You can't get a completed countdown and an abort at the same time.). If `BenchTimer()` completes, then it sends "Complete" down the channel. If `AbortTest()` "completes" it sends "Abort" down the channel. [So far this all seems to be working...]

The next problem I ran into with this setup is how to kill the Goroutine that wasn't the "winner"... (i.e. If `BenchTimer()` completes normally, then I need to somehow kill `AbortTest()`... and vice-versa.) After a bunch of searching, I found that it isn't possible to kill a Goroutine externally, but it can be done internally... so I came up with using a second channel for each Goroutine to act as a sort of "kill signal" line: `killAbortTest` and `killBenchTimer`.

To tie this all together, I evaluate the result of the `testAction` channel. Because this channel will tell me which Goroutine "won", I can use this knowledge to send the correct (i.e. opposite) "kill signal" to have the "loser" Goroutine self-terminate.

Note: `...` just means other code exists, but was removed due to not being needed for this post.

```
func main() {
...

testAction := make(chan string)             // Action Result (Timer "Complete" or User "Abort")
killAbortTest := make(chan bool)            // Kill AbortTest() Goroutine when BenchTimer() completes.
killBenchTimer := make(chan bool)           // Kill BenchTimer() Goroutine when AbortTest() completes.

go BenchTimer(testAction, killBenchTimer)   // Run BenchTimer() as Goroutine
go AbortTest(testAction, killAbortTest)     // Run AbortTest() as Goroutine

// Program should wait here until it receives something on testAction channel.
actionVal := <-testAction

// Evaluate the testAction to kill the "loser" Goroutine
switch actionVal {
    case "Abort":
        killBenchTimer <- true             // Abort received, signal BenchTimer() Goroutine to Quit
        fmt.Println()
        fmt.Println("Test Aborted")
    case "Complete":
        killAbortTest <- true             // Countdown finished, signal AbortTest() Goroutine to Quit
        fmt.Println()
        fmt.Println("Test Completed")
}
...
}
```

```
// AbortTest - Listen for User Abort
func AbortTest(c chan<- string, k <-chan bool) {

if err := keyboard.Open(); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer func() {
    _ = keyboard.Close()
}()
for {
    select {
        case <-k:
            return
        default:
            _, key, err := keyboard.GetKey()  // Poll for keypress
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
            if key == keyboard.KeyEsc {       // ESC key was pressed
                c <- "Abort"
                return
            }
    }
}
}
```

```
// BenchTimer - Countdown Timer for BenchTest
func BenchTimer(c chan<- string, k <-chan bool) {

seconds := 0

switch testTime {
    case "2-minute (fast)":
        seconds = 120
    case "5-minute (short)":
        seconds = 300
    case "10-minute (long)":
        seconds = 600
    case "20-minute (slow)":
        seconds = 1200
}

ticker := time.Tick(time.Second)
for i := seconds; i >= 0; i-- {
    select {
        case <-k:         // Kill Signal Received
            return
        default:
            <-ticker
            ...
    }
}
c <- "Complete"
}
```

There it is. My mess. There are many like it, but this one is my own. Like I said, it sorta works now, but I'm looking to make it better.

Am I just overthinking this whole process and making it way more complex than it needs to be?

Any help would be great.

Comment: "wrongly" is a word, yes. :-) A "done" channel is a common Go idiom. I can't comment on any of the code I can't see, but selecting on the done channel and the other channel is quite common.

Comment: Use a single done channel and close the channel after the line `actionVal := <-testAction`.  This allows you to remove the code to send values to the goroutine specific done channels and prevents main from blocking forever should one of the goroutines not receive on its channel.

Comment: you dont really need AbortTest to listen for completed event. it will exit when main exits. and move that `defer keyboard.Close()` in main. If needed, i am not sure it is required to close the keyboard resource upon exit sequence. It might just be harmless.

Answer (score -1):

<s>This is the simplest example I can think of. I left out the keyboard part, but its basically the idea behind your code :</s>

As mentioned by **mh-cbon**, this is safe :

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func main() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    wg.Add(2)
    go DoSomeTask(ctx, cancel)
    go CancelTask(ctx, cancel)
    wg.Wait()
}

func DoSomeTask(ctx context.Context, cancel func()) {
    defer wg.Done()
    defer cancel() // force cancellation
    for i := 1; i < 10; i++ {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            fmt.Println("context cancelled")
            return
        case <-time.After(time.Second):
        }
        fmt.Println("Done something!", i)
    }
}

func CancelTask(ctx context.Context, cancel func()) {
    defer wg.Done()
    defer cancel() // force cancellation
    duration := time.Second * time.Duration((rand.Intn(20-1) + 1))
    fmt.Println("Will cancel in ", duration, " seconds!")
    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        fmt.Println("context cancelled")
    case <-time.After(duration):
    }
}
```

Comment: your solution is probrlematic as two routines are closing the channel, becasue one channel will write on a closed channel, and that by design one of those routines will always become dangling. (two writes, one read)

Comment: @mh-cbon is right. Also, there's also a chance that main goroutine exits before you close the channel. Also, there could be a scenario when you sending to a closed channel which will cause a `panic`.

Comment: @mh-cbon Is it better now? If I defer the closure of the channel in the main routine and remove it from the asyn funcs? ( i have edited )

Comment: there is still a possibility for a write to occur on a closed channel. Given that code, it wont trigger always, but in real situation, where code changes often that is source of errors. Having two routines writing on a channel with unsynchronize close is a well known anti pattern. There must be a condition and only one that triggers the close of a channel in a synchronized fashion.

Comment: that is why in my play there is only one routine responsible to close the channel. i also wrote the program in such way that both routines must end before the program exits. though re reading it, i wrote too quickly and there is a possibility it blocks waiting on the cancellation condition to be met. this is better https://play.golang.org/p/YTo2l-t3FAD

Comment: @mh-cbon thanks! Ill add your code since its better and mention it.

Comment: note also that it is possible to get ride of the waitgroup and use `ctx.Done` as a wait condition in `main`